# Thunderbird crash report right after start

Tags: windows-10, email, thunderbird, crash

I have a problem with Thunderbird from some days. When I try to start it, it crash right after start and only I see window for "Crash reporting tool" from Thunderbird. I don;'t know what happened. i try:

1. Reinstall Thunderbird (using Geek Uninstaller and manual delete
   profiles etc)
2. Delete profiles and then try to start Thunderbird
3. Create new profile wit "-p" parametr and open that way

Any of above method don't work - I always see crash reporting tool. I also try to open portable version and that version start.
I think that happened after some Windows Update (os Windows 10), but when I looked at installed updates it's only for Office and NET framework.

Any ideas what else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First, thoroughly clean up remnants of Thunderbird:

- Save your old profile to another folder.
- Completely remove Thunderbird using *Programs and Features*.
- Remove any remaining data from Thunderbird (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird`) and data (`C:\ProgramData\Mozilla`, `C:\Users\Bart\AppData\Local\Thunderbird`,`C:\Users\Bart\AppData\LocalLow\Mozilla`, and `C:\Users\Bart\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird`).
- Open Regedit, search for any data containing `Thunderbird`, and delete the key (using due care!).

Now try [reinstalling 32-bit Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/download/) (the default).

If everything works, you can now *switch* some of the new files with those from your old profile to avoid reentering account information, view, etc. *Keep those new profile files, in case something is borked in the old batch.*